# Java how to use TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary

I have an TreeMap with for key an Integer and for value Coords (int x, int y).
I would like to get all the values (my coords) associated with an specific key.
For exemple :

```
key = 1, coords = [0, 0]  
key = 1, coords = [0, 1]  
key = 2, coords = [1, 0]  
key = 3, coords = [1, 1]  

foreach myMap.getKeys() as key   
do    
    myMap.getValuesFrom(key)  
    store it in a new list 
end do
```

I don't really know how to use Map,  your helps is welcome.

Comment: That doesn't look like Java to me.

Comment: It's not java, just an algorithm

Comment: Did you really just ask for a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point - `Map` cannot have two different values associated with the same key. If you really need to do this, you can create a map of lists, like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
```

The following code traverses the keys of the map and puts related values to the list:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
    list.add(map.get(key));
}
```

More correct way to do the same thing:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
```

If you really need several values mapped to the same key, try this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Map values for key \"" + entry.getKey() + "\":");
    for (Integer value : entry.getValue() == null ? new ArrayList<Integer>() : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This code simply writes all map keys and its values into `System.out`.

For further information, try to read [Map Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [List Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: @melkir You're welcome. Do not forget to upvote useful answers and select the best as correct.

Comment: It seems that I don't have enough reputation to do this maybe I have missed something, sorry :(

Comment: @melkir You should always be able to select preferred answer. Upvote may require reputation, but that thing is available for everybody.

Comment: Thank's ! Didn't see the "v" button !